# Why did Italy's Battle for Births fail?

Tags: italy, population, mussolini

According to [Wikipedia:Battle for Births](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_for_Births):

> The Battle for Births began in 1927: Mussolini introduced a number of measures to encourage reproduction, with an objective of increasing the population from 40 million to 60 million by 1950
>
> ...
>
> By 1950 ... Italy's population stood at 47.5 million

The article describes Italy's attempt at increasing it's population, by providing monetary support to parents, implementing a tax on bachelors, and having civil services promoting fertile and married people. However, the birth and marriage rates showed no significant change.

Did Mussolini actually believe he could raise the population to 60 million? And if so, why couldn't he? Was WW2 a factor?

Comment: [Battle for Births: The Fascist Pronatalist Campaign in Italy 1925 to 1938](https://anthrosource.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1556-5823.2010.00002.x) should prove useful if you can access it.

Comment: I would upvote an answer that compared it to other government efforts to "manage" population.  I know the Soviets tried it, the Chinese tried it (in a different direction), etc.   Of course in a fascist state, there properly should be no personal decisions; all individual desires should be subordinate to the state.  That said, my rewrite of the title would be, "What kind of deluded idiot thinks that personal reproductive decisions should be made by the state?"   (and yes, that is intentionally a leading question)

Comment: Yes, one would indeed imagine that having WWII march lengthwise through Italian territory probably didn't help. The Great Depression I think tanked population growth in developed nations worldwide too.

Comment: One can look at, e.g., https://www.infoplease.com/us/population/live-births-and-birth-rates-year to see what the US births and birth rates were doing during that time. Depression and war don't seem to help things much.

Comment: @JonCuster None of the actual fighting was in the US, however. And even so, births in the 1930's and 1940's were depressed compared to the 1920's

Comment: @Spencer - correct (plus or minus Attu and Kiska), but that shows what happened somewhere else, with fewer issues (although 10 million men were in uniform). And, the birth rates drop pretty dramatically in the Depression and through the war, were back to 1925 levels by the early 1950's, but never got back to 1920 levels even during the post-war baby boom.

Comment: Considering the little known fact of WW2 :)  it could be said that Mussolini's Battle for Births was in fact great success.

Comment: @T.E.D and rs.29: looking at the population pyramids available on the internet (but which get filtered out when trying to link here) it seems like WWII led to about 500 000 missing births. The number of Italians killed in WWII is also about 500 000, so the war can only explain part of the shortfall.

Comment: @Jan Half of million dead plus hundreds of thousands POWs, plus lack of food, shelter etc ... You could estimate lost births in a range of ten million. With 47.5 present in 1950 that is close to objective of 60 million. Note that Italy before WW2 included North and East African colonies.

Comment: @rs.29 I am sure one could make lots and lots of estimations, but there is actual statistical data available. IMHO https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Italy shows 100,000 to 150,000 missing births per year 1940 to 1945, followed by maybe 50,000 *additional* births 1946 to 1948. Of course your interpretation may vary, but 10 million missing births seems quite hard to justify.

Comment: Most people would probably disagree that a population increase of 7.5 million is "close to" a population increase of 20 million, but that sure this is something a politician might have said if asked in 1950. Citation needed that the 40 millions in 1927 included Lybia, Eritrea or Somalia.

Comment: @Jan I don't don't know where did you find your 100-150 thousand missing per year. All I could see is that number of live births was increasing up to 1940, and then fell by almost 200 000 per year. Considering that it did not EVER ! recover to 1940 level, I would say that the loss is substantial, i.e. at least in ballpark of ten million. Btw, if you came to prove a political point (Mussolini bad and stupid, need to find why ) then you are barking up wrong tree .

Comment: @rs.29 I was referring to politicians in general, not any particular ones. Neither to any particular political parties. Even 200 000 per year for ten years (1940 to 1950) would be a lot less than 10 millions according to my calculator.

Comment: @Jan You are not calculating lost growth of births  in a decade that followed (1941-1950) , plus of course excess mortality not directly related to being killed in war (i.e. disease, malnourishment etc ...)

Comment: @rs.29 OP is about timeframe up to 1950.

Answer (score -2):

> However, the birth and marriage rates showed no significant change.

True, China has currently exactly the same problem, for almost the same reasons.

> Did Mussolini actually believe he could raise the population to 60 million?

Probably. Otherwise, why bother?

> And if so, why couldn't he? Was WW2 a factor?

No. Do the math: Mussolini ordered Italians to *'hide the salami'* more often in 1927. The age of conscription was 18 years. The first batch would be ready in 1945. Even in 1927, his order came too late to be of any significance during WW2.

Demographics is like a mammoth tanker: slow and very difficult to change course. Once you realize you're going to run into something, it's already too late. No matter what you do, the accident will happen.

The Chinese government is discovering this right now. It's not easy to order people to do something they don't want to do. Especially if that something is expensive and time-consuming.

Raising children is very expensive. Especially as the Chinese government wants everybody to have 3 or more children. That means the mother has to stay home, and cannot provide additional income. With 3 or more children, subsidized daycare simply doesn't cut it. One also needs a bigger house. Houses are extremely expensive in China. For an ordinary family, it is simply not possible to have 3 children.

There is another issue the Chinese government didn't consider: after a full generation grew up as a single child, that generation simply doesn't want larger families. If they want children at all - many young couples do not want any children, not even one.

Getting back to Mussolini: one of the reasons his plan didn't work is that he wanted the benefit (for the state) of many children, but was not willing to pay for it. Parents followed the party line, but only where it made sense. Going into poverty because Mussolini wants more children made very little sense. Yes, there were definite benefits, as @Lars Bosteen said in the comments. But not enough to make it worthwhile for most families.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Yes, I am sure. Hi did give those benefits, but it was not enough. Otherwise, people would have jumped at eac... it.

Comment: Are there any available numbers for the benefits offered and cost of living at the time?

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by explaining how WWII was not a factor. I actually agree with that point, but after all wars lead both to significantly more deaths and significantly less births.

Comment: @Jan 1927+18=1945. It's of course possible to sent 12/14 year-olds to battle, as Germany did.

Comment: @Jos My understanding of that question is "Was WWII part of the reason why Italy's population in 1950 was less than 60 million?" It seems your understanding is "Was WWII part of the reason why Mussolini wanted a population of 60 million in 1950?" Is that right?